# Automating a timer when I open the computer in macOS

Tags: macos, timer, automation

I want to automate a program which kind of notifies me when 30 minutes since I opened the computer is up - so it tells me after 30 minutes of continuous screen time. I want to know how to do this in macOS Catalina. If there is an option to kind of give a notification when the time is up, that's great, but if I have to write a program that's ok also. I can easily write a program to play an audio after 30 minutes in Python - but how do I make it automatically start when I open the computer?

Thanks in advance. Note: I am on macOS Catalina 10.15.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use login script which will be run automatically when you login :

```
  Start Script Editor, create new document and paste following line of code:
  do shell script "/usr/bin/python $HOME/screentime.py"
     Save it:
     Save As : LoginScript
     Where : Applications
     File Format : Application

  Goto System Preferences->Users & Groups->Login Items
     Click "+" to add "LoginScript"
```

Comment: Where should `screentime.py` be?

Comment: You can put wherever is convenient, maybe $HOME/scripts/py.

Comment: Is it ok if I put it in the Documents folder?

Comment: should be no problem. If you want python3, change `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: So the command in LoginScript should be `do shell script "/usr/bin/python3/screentime.py"`?

Comment: You can try `do shell script "/usr/bin/python3 $HOME/Documents/screentime.py"`